# Properties of numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be any natural number such that $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\ldots p_r^{e_r}$. if  $n-(e_1+1)(e_2+1)\ldots (e_r+1)=1$, then n=3 or n=4. Is there any general formala, i.e what are the natural numbers such that $n-(e_1+1)(e_2+1)\ldots (e_r+1)=k$, where k is any natural number?

Answer (score 1):

$(e_1+1)(e_2+1)\cdots(e_r+1)$ is $d(n)$, the number of divisors of $n$. The number of solutions to $n-d(n)=k$, $k=0,1,2,\dots$, is tabulated at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A060990). There isn't much information about the sequence there, and that and its irregularities suggest that there's no general formula for the natural numbers with $n-d(n)=k$.

Answer (score 0):

Put $(e_1+1)(e_2+1)\ldots (e_r+1)=t$.

If $f_1$ is the number of $e_i=1$ then each contributes $(1+1)$ to the product $t$, so the total contribution to $t$ is $(1+1)^{f_1}$

If $f_2$ is the number of $e_i=2$ then each contributes $(1+2)$ to the product $t$, so the total contribution to $t$ is $(1+2)^{f_2}$

If $f_j$ is the number of $e_i=j$ then each contributes $(1+j)$ to the product $t$, so the total contribution to $t$ is $(1+j)^{f_j}$

So $t=(1+1)^{f_1}(1+2)^{f_2}\ldots (1+j)^{f_j}$

$$t=\prod_{j}\big((1+j)^{f_j}\big)\tag1$$

$$k=n-t$$

**Example.** $$n=1080450=(2)(3^2)(5^2)(7^4)$$

$$t=(1+1)^1(1+2)^2(1+4)^1=(2)(3)^2(5)=90$$

$$k=n-t=1080360$$